# Highcharts : Under Y Axis we need to display a Image

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Please see the Highcharts related jsfiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-dual-axes/

This is my Y axis

```
{
 // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value +' mm';
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }
```

Typically what i want is that  ,  under  the Y axis Secondary Axis  label (that is below 250 mm here in this case  ) , i need to display the Temparature series Symbol

Could anybody please help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why you want a symbol for temperature on the rainfall side, but let me see if I can help.

Well, if you just want to display a picture in the same place on your chart, then use the highcharts renderer. [Highcharts drawing API](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/24-highcharts-drawing-api-documented). In this case, just use the image(...) function.

I'm not finding simple ways of doing more dynamic bits. There are some enforcements of the css for the axis's that prevent anything but text to show up.  You may be able to dig into the axis (in the formatter; this.axis) and find something useful.  But you may have more luck running jQuery code to find the location of the text you want, then using offset(), find where in the page to slap your image onto.  Either using a div or the highchart.Renderer.

Good luck!